# MySQL - how to show some field in select query that accept my condition

Tags: mysql

I have database like this:
[image]

For `id=2`, I want to show fields `[jp1-jp15]` that are `1`.

That means, I want to see:

```
[jp1-jp2-jp3-jp4-jp5-jp7-jp8-jp9-jp10-jp12-jp13-jp14]
```

as a result of MySQL query.

Comment: Answer: You don't do this, not without some really ugly code.  My feeling is that perhaps these columns should really be spread out across _rows_.  Why did you design your table this way?

Comment: Fix your schema. A database table is not a spreadsheet

Comment: @Strawberry It's not?  Wow...learn something new every day on this site :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try using `IF` combined with `CONCAT_WS`:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT_WS('-', IF(jp1=1, 'jp1', NULL), IF(jp2=1, 'jp2', NULL),
        IF(jp3=1, 'jp3', NULL), IF(jp4=1, 'jp4', NULL),
        ...
        IF(jp14=1, 'jp14', NULL)) AS csv
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo